# Continuous Delivery for multi component Project

Tags: continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

In our project we have multiple components developed by separate teams having separate git repos.
All components have commit job and packaging job and publishes the artifacts to artifactory.

The problem comes when we want to deploy all the components as a system.

Since all these components deploys to separate servers and then interact with each other for functioning.. a lot of time inconsistencies arises due to some newer version of a component being deployed to one of the server.

For ex. I have components A,B,C and want to move following versions A1, B1, C1 in the deployment and testing pipeline. How I can ensure that no newer version of a component is deployed to QA environment (servers). I am using Jenkins as my CI/CD tool. It seems I need some integration or lightweight configuration management tool to manage the versioning of my system as a whole comprising of all components which I can promote in the deployment pipeline.

I hope I could describe my question. Suggestions to tackle this situation will be really helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use this pattern:

- for every customer which uses our products there is one "project": It contains nearly no code, just configuration. We use this name scheme: coreapp_customerslug.
- the project depends on N applications. The project pins all exact versions of the dependencies.

During CI we do this:

1. install project P and all the pinned dependencies
2. Then update all dependencies to their latest version.
3. Run all tests
4. If all tests succeed, update the versions of the dependencies and increment the version of the project.
5. Now the project has a new and stable release.
6. deploy the new release (at the moment we don't do this automatically, but in the near future).

With this pattern ("project" is an container of the apps) you can handle the version problem. If you have several servers, the update process should be fast, to avoid different versions at the same time.

**Update**

The CI maintains the pinned versions. We use python and pip and the file requirements.txt gets updated by a script. We use the version schema YYYY.N. N gets incremented if all tests are ok.

Attention: If app1 has latest version N, this does not mean that it works in all projects. If you have two projects: P1 and P2, this can happen: app1 with latest version N works well in project P1, but fails in P2. This means you can't create a new stable version of project P2. Sometimes this is annoying, but this keeps a constant update alive. We always use the latest version of our apps in ours projects.

Comment: Thanks guettli, I have one query in this solution. i.e. who maintains the pinned dependency versions in project P. How you update dependency version in project P configurations, is there an automated way to capture latest versions of dependencies and update configuration in project P?